# How to keep the beginning and end of sentence markers with quanteda

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, tm, quanteda

I'm trying to create 3-grams using R's `quanteda` package.

I'm struggling to find a way to keep in the n-grams beginning and end of sentence markers, the `<s>` and `</s>` as in the code below.

I thought that using the `keptFeatures` with a regular expression that matched those should maintain them but the chevron markers are always removed.

How can I keep the chevron markers from being removed or what is the best way to delimit beginning and end of sentence with `quanteda`?

As a bonus question what is the advantage of `docfreq(mydfm)` over `colSums(mydfm)`, the result of str(colSums(mydfm)) and str(docfreq(mydfm)) is almost identical (`Named num [1:n]` the former, `Named int [1:n]` the latter)?

```
library(quanteda)
text <- "<s>I'm a sentence and I'd better be formatted properly!</s><s>I'm a second sentence</s>"

qc <- corpus(text)

mydfm  <- dfm(qc, ngram=3, removeNumbers = F, stem=T, keptFeatures="\\</?s\\>")

names(colSums(mydfm))

# Output:
# [1] "s_i'm_a"    "i'm_a_sentenc"    "a_sentenc_and"    "sentenc_and_i'd"
# [2] "and_i'd_better"   "i'd_better_be"    "better_be_format"   
# [3] "be_format_proper" "format_proper_s"  "proper_s_s"   "s_s_i'm"    
# [4] "i'm_a_second"   "a_second_sentenc"   "second_sentenc_s"
```

**EDIT:**

Corrected keepFeatures to keptFeatures in code snippet.

Comment: Not that it solves the problem, but `keptFeatures` is the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return a simple vector, just unlist the `tokenizedText" object returned from`tokenize()`(which is a specially classed list, with additional attributes).  Here I used the`what = "fasterword"`which splits on "\\s" -- it's a tiny bit smarter than`what = "fastestword"`which splits on`" "`.

```
# how to not remove the <s>, and return a vector 
unlist(toks <- tokenize(text, ngrams = 3, what = "fasterword"))
## [1] "<s>I'm_a_sentence"                "a_sentence_and"                  
## [3] "sentence_and_I'd"                 "and_I'd_better"                  
## [5] "I'd_better_be"                    "better_be_formatted"             
## [7] "be_formatted_properly!</s><s>I'm" "formatted_properly!</s><s>I'm_a" 
## [9] "properly!</s><s>I'm_a_second"     "a_second_sentence</s>"
```

To keep it within sentence, tokenise the object twice, the first time by sentence, the second time by `fasterword`.

```
# keep it within sentence
(sents <- unlist(tokenize(text, what = "sentence")))
## [1] "<s>I'm a sentence and I'd better be formatted properly!"
## [2] "</s><s>I'm a second sentence</s>" 
tokenize(sents, ngrams = 3, what = "fasterword")
## tokenizedText object from 2 documents.
## Component 1 :
## [1] "<s>I'm_a_sentence"      "a_sentence_and"         "sentence_and_I'd"       "and_I'd_better"        
## [5] "I'd_better_be"          "better_be_formatted"    "be_formatted_properly!"
## 
## Component 2 :
## [1] "</s><s>I'm_a_second"   "a_second_sentence</s>"
```

To preserve the chevron markers in a dfm, you can pass through the same options that you used above in the `tokenize()` call, since `dfm()` calls `tokenize()` but with different defaults -- it uses the ones most users will probably want, whereas `tokenize()` is much more conservative.

```
# Bonus questions:
myDfm <- dfm(text, verbose = FALSE, what = "fasterword", removePunct = FALSE)
# "chevron" markers are not removed
features(myDfm)
## [1] "<s>i'm"              "a"                   "sentence"            "and"                 "i'd"                
## [6] "better"              "be"                  "formatted"           "properly!</s><s>i'm" "second"             
## [11] "sentence</s>"
```

Final part of the bonus question was the difference between `docfreq()` and `colSums()`.  The former returns the count of documents in which a term occurs, the latter sums the columns to get a total term frequency across documents.  See below how different these are for the term `"representatives"`.

```
# Difference between docfreq() and colSums():
myDfm2 <- dfm(inaugTexts[1:4], verbose = FALSE)
myDfm2[, "representatives"]
docfreq(myDfm2)["representatives"]
colSums(myDfm2)["representatives"]
## Document-feature matrix of: 4 documents, 1 feature.
## 4 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
##                  features
## docs              representatives
##   1789-Washington               2
##   1793-Washington               0
##   1797-Adams                    2
##   1801-Jefferson                0
docfreq(myDfm2)["representatives"]
## representatives 
##               2 
colSums(myDfm2)["representatives"]
## representatives 
##               4
```

**Update: Some commands and behaviours have changed in quanteda v0.9.9:**

Return a simple vector, retaining chevrons:

```
as.character(toks <- tokens(text, ngrams = 3, what = "fasterword"))
#  [1] "<s>I'm_a_sentence"                "a_sentence_and"                   "sentence_and_I'd"                
#  [4] "and_I'd_better"                   "I'd_better_be"                    "better_be_formatted"             
#  [7] "be_formatted_properly!</s><s>I'm" "formatted_properly!</s><s>I'm_a"  "properly!</s><s>I'm_a_second"    
# [10] "a_second_sentence</s>"
```

Keeping within sentence:

```
(sents <- as.character(tokens(text, what = "sentence")))
# [1] "<s>I'm a sentence and I'd better be formatted properly!" "</s><s>I'm a second sentence</s>"                       
tokens(sents, ngrams = 3, what = "fasterword")
# tokens from 2 documents.
# Component 1 :
# [1] "<s>I'm_a_sentence"      "a_sentence_and"         "sentence_and_I'd"       "and_I'd_better"         "I'd_better_be"         
# [6] "better_be_formatted"    "be_formatted_properly!"
# 
# Component 2 :
# [1] "</s><s>I'm_a_second"   "a_second_sentence</s>"
```

Bonus question part 1:

```
featnames(dfm(text, verbose = FALSE, what = "fasterword", removePunct = FALSE))
#  [1] "<s>i'm"              "a"                   "sentence"            "and"                 "i'd"                
#  [6] "better"              "be"                  "formatted"           "properly!</s><s>i'm" "second"             
# [11] "sentence</s>"
```

Bonus question part 2 is unchanged.

Comment: Excellent package!!  Why are some of the ngrams containing more than 3 words, like `"be_formatted_properly!</s><s>I'm"`.  Looks like some of the end of sentence tags are getting grouped with beginning of sentence tags, like `"</s><s>I'm_a_second"`

Comment: Thanks! Why: Because "fasterword" splits on whitespace, and there is no whitespace there. Easiest way to fix this is to gsub the text beforehand to replace `</s><s>` with `</s> <s>`, or to use the `segment()` method as suggested by @Jota.

Answer (score 1):

How about an approach like this:

```
ngrams(
  tokenize(
    unlist(
      segment(text, what = "other", delimiter = "(?<=\\</s\\>)", perl = TRUE)),
    what = "fastestword", simplify = TRUE),
  n = 3L)

# [1] "<s>I'm_a_sentence"              "a_sentence_and"                
# [3] "sentence_and_I'd"               "and_I'd_better"                
# [5] "I'd_better_be"                  "better_be_formatted"           
# [7] "be_formatted_properly!</s>"     "formatted_properly!</s>_<s>I'm"
# [9] "properly!</s>_<s>I'm_a"         "<s>I'm_a_second"               
#[11] "a_second_sentence</s>"
```

Or, if you don't want ngrams that cross sentence boundaries:

```
unlist(
  ngrams(
    tokenize(
      unlist(
        segment(text, what = "other", delimiter = "(?<=\\</s\\>)", perl = TRUE)),
      what = "fastestword"),
    n = 3L))
#[1] "<s>I'm_a_sentence"          "a_sentence_and"            
#[3] "sentence_and_I'd"           "and_I'd_better"            
#[5] "I'd_better_be"              "better_be_formatted"       
#[7] "be_formatted_properly!</s>" "<s>I'm_a_second"           
#[9] "a_second_sentence</s>"
```

I left the customizing options (e.g. `removePunct = TRUE`, etc.) up to you.

Comment: Different syntax but achieves the goal, thanks! Peculiar that the `dfm` seem not to respect the `keptFeatures`, still curious if there is a way to have it work, anyway your answer shows more than one way to solve my problem, I'll mark as accepted answer.